# Best Dependecy Injection Technology for Play Framework

Tags: playframework

What is the best dependency injection technology framework for play framework?

Comment: I'd say "best" is very subjective. Here's a list of DI-frameworks that work with Play: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaDependencyInjection

Comment: You should do some searches (like "guice vs spring") and check what is the better for you. In my case I only used Guice and apart a little problem from jar versions it works very well. In Java world you have [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaInjection) examples with Guice and Spring.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one right answer for your question but it is worth to mention that from version 2.4 Play is going to ship with build-in Guice support.

You can read more about dependency injection in the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24).

> Out of the box we provide and encourage the use of Guice for
>   dependency injection, but many other dependency injection tools and
>   techniques, including compile time dependency injection techniques in
>   Scala are possible.

You are not forced to use Guice but definitely if Play developers suggest this framework it is advised to check it out especially with a future migration of your application to newer version of Play in your mind.